# Combining 2 SQL Queries

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have one complicated query that converts date and time variables from numeric values into a more user friendly output AND I have a second sql query that is a simple join between two tables. I'm trying to combine these two SQL Queries into one in which I can access all the information with more efficiency.

This is my first query:

```
   Select * from Media 
   join (SELECT convert(date, 
   DATEADD(HOUR,-4,CONVERT(DATETIME,LEFT([Date],8)+' '+ 
   SUBSTRING([Date],10,2)+':'+ 
   SUBSTRING([Date],12,2)+':'+ 
   SUBSTRING([Date],14,2)+'.'+ 
   SUBSTRING([Date],15,3)))) [Date], 
   convert(varchar(8), convert(time, 
   DATEADD(HOUR,-4,CONVERT(DATETIME,LEFT([Date],8)+' '+ 
   SUBSTRING([Date],10,2)+':'+ 
   SUBSTRING([Date],12,2)+':'+ 
   SUBSTRING([Date],14,2)+'.'+ 
   SUBSTRING([Date],15,3))))) [Time], 
   [Object] AS [Dataset], 
   SUBSTRING(Parms,1,6) AS [Media] 
   FROM (Select CONVERT(VARCHAR(18),[Date]) [Date], 
   [Object], 
   MsgId, 
   Parms 
   FROM JnlDataSection) A 
   Where MsgID = '325' AND 
   SUBSTRING(Parms,1,6) like 'V754%') b on Media.SerialNum = b.Media order by Date  Desc, Time Desc
```

This is my second query:

```
   SELECT SerialNum, m.MediaId, n.Note  as Note 
   from Media m join Note n on (m.NoteId = n.NoteId)
   where SerialNum like 'V754%';
```

What I have tried:

```
   Select * m.MediaId, n.Note  as Note from Media m join Note n on (m.NoteId =  n.NoteId)
   join (SELECT convert(date, 
   DATEADD(HOUR,-4,CONVERT(DATETIME,LEFT([Date],8)+' '+ 
   SUBSTRING([Date],10,2)+':'+ 
   SUBSTRING([Date],12,2)+':'+ 
   SUBSTRING([Date],14,2)+'.'+ 
   SUBSTRING([Date],15,3)))) [Date], 
   convert(varchar(8), convert(time, 
   DATEADD(HOUR,-4,CONVERT(DATETIME,LEFT([Date],8)+' '+ 
   SUBSTRING([Date],10,2)+':'+ 
   SUBSTRING([Date],12,2)+':'+ 
   SUBSTRING([Date],14,2)+'.'+ 
   SUBSTRING([Date],15,3))))) [Time], 
   [Object] AS [Dataset], 
   SUBSTRING(Parms,1,6) AS [Media] 
   FROM (Select CONVERT(VARCHAR(18),[Date]) [Date], 
   [Object], 
   MsgId, 
   Parms 
   FROM JnlDataSection) A 
   Where MsgID = '325' AND 
   SUBSTRING(Parms,1,6) like 'V754%') b on Media.SerialNum = b.Media order by Date  Desc, Time Desc
```

But this is giving me this error:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
>   Incorrect syntax near 'm'.
>   Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 22
>   Incorrect syntax near 'b'.

Please note I'm using SQL Server 2008 Management Studio. Also I am not interested in changing any of the column or data manipulation for the queries as it already fits my needs appropriately. I'm merely looking for a combined query that runs error free in SQL.

Comment: Could you indicate the line numbers where the error occurs?

Comment: Also I just noticed that you alias "Media" as "m" but then at the very end still refer to is as "Media" in `on Media.SerialNum = b.Media`

Comment: Try adding a comma after the select.  You've got this "Select * m.MediaId," try this "Select *, m.MediaId,"

Comment: When you say combine, you mean `UNION`? If this is what you want, the first and second query need to return the same fields

Comment: @BWS It is giving me this error on the last line now.  Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 30
The multi-part identifier "Media.SerialNum" could not be bound.

Comment: @Christiandev is it possible for you to show me the syntax with union all and use my queries as an example?  They can return all fields such as (*) for simplicity purposes.

Answer (score 1):

in the code 'you have tried', the syntax is wrong...try below code, I have only fixed the error though.

```
SELECT   m.MediaId,
             n.Note AS Note
    FROM     Media AS m
             INNER JOIN
             Note AS n
             ON (m.NoteId = n.NoteId)
             INNER JOIN
             (SELECT CONVERT (DATE, DATEADD(HOUR, -4, CONVERT (DATETIME, LEFT([Date], 8) + ' ' + SUBSTRING([Date], 10, 2) + ':' + SUBSTRING([Date], 12, 2) + ':' + SUBSTRING([Date], 14, 2) + '.' + SUBSTRING([Date], 15, 3)))) AS [Date],
                     CONVERT (VARCHAR (8), CONVERT (TIME, DATEADD(HOUR, -4, CONVERT (DATETIME, LEFT([Date], 8) + ' ' + SUBSTRING([Date], 10, 2) + ':' + SUBSTRING([Date], 12, 2) + ':' + SUBSTRING([Date], 14, 2) + '.' + SUBSTRING([Date], 15, 3))))) AS [Time],
                     [Object] AS [Dataset],
                     SUBSTRING(Parms, 1, 6) AS [Media]
              FROM   (SELECT CONVERT (VARCHAR (18), [Date]) AS [Date],
                             [Object],
                             MsgId,
                             Parms
                      FROM   JnlDataSection) AS A
              WHERE  MsgID = '325'
                     AND SUBSTRING(Parms, 1, 6) LIKE 'V754%') AS b
             ON m.SerialNum = b.Media
    ORDER BY Date DESC, Time DESC;
```

With Union of the first two queries...

```
SELECT  Media.SerialNum ,
        Media.MediaId ,
        'Note' AS Notes
FROM    Media
        JOIN ( SELECT   CONVERT(DATE, DATEADD(HOUR, -4,
                                              CONVERT(DATETIME, LEFT([Date], 8)
                                              + ' ' + SUBSTRING([Date], 10, 2)
                                              + ':' + SUBSTRING([Date], 12, 2)
                                              + ':' + SUBSTRING([Date], 14, 2)
                                              + '.' + SUBSTRING([Date], 15, 3)))) [Date] ,
                        CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), CONVERT(TIME, DATEADD(HOUR, -4,
                                                              CONVERT(DATETIME, LEFT([Date],
                                                              8) + ' '
                                                              + SUBSTRING([Date],
                                                              10, 2) + ':'
                                                              + SUBSTRING([Date],
                                                              12, 2) + ':'
                                                              + SUBSTRING([Date],
                                                              14, 2) + '.'
                                                              + SUBSTRING([Date],
                                                              15, 3))))) [Time] ,
                        [Object] AS [Dataset] ,
                        SUBSTRING(Parms, 1, 6) AS [Media]
               FROM     ( SELECT    CONVERT(VARCHAR(18), [Date]) [Date] ,
                                    [Object] ,
                                    MsgId ,
                                    Parms
                          FROM      JnlDataSection
                        ) A
               WHERE    MsgID = '325'
                        AND SUBSTRING(Parms, 1, 6) LIKE 'V754%'
             ) b ON m.SerialNum = b.Media
UNION
SELECT  SerialNum ,
        m.MediaId ,
        n.Note AS Notes
FROM    Media m
        JOIN Note n ON ( m.NoteId = n.NoteId )
WHERE   SerialNum LIKE 'V754%'
```

but, I dont know what data type `Note` is in the first query?

Comment: it is giving me this error now on the second last line.  Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 19
The multi-part identifier "Media.SerialNum" could not be bound.

Comment: it is being executed but no data is being displayed.. Just the column names.  However when I run the two queries separately it shows me the data regarding v754 media

Comment: Note is a nvarchar(3800), not null value.

Comment: it gives an error in which the line says union.  Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 35
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'UNION'.

Comment: Note is actually a table and it contains a column name of Note as well.  But I am receiving this error with ur new edit:

Comment: Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 32
The multi-part identifier "m.SerialNum" could not be bound.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 41
Invalid column name 'Date'.
Msg 104, Level 16, State 1, Line 41
ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if the statement contains a UNION, INTERSECT or EXCEPT operator.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 42
Invalid column name 'Time'.
Msg 104, Level 16, State 1, Line 42
ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if the statement contains a UNION, INTERSECT or EXCEPT operator.

Comment: @omarK, you don't need the Order by clause, and the Note table isn't being queried in the first table, but you still need to supply some value for it, so I just added '' as the placeholder to match the 2nd query.

Answer (score 0):

At the very least you have an error in the first few lines:
You have this:      Select * m.MediaId, n.Note  as Note 
But you need this:  Select m.MediaId, n.Note  as Note, *

Comment: it is giving me this error now on the second last line. Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 19 The multi-part identifier "Media.SerialNum" could not be bound.

Comment: Please post exactly as you are running it when you get the error.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that UNION or UNION ALL is suitable to this issue:

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp

Best